# how to remove nan values from a matrix keeping matrix size same

Tags: matlab, matrix

I obtained a matrix by doing some calculation.

```
th1 =

    0.3333    0.6667    0.2500       NaN
    0.5000         0       NaN    0.5000
    0.5000       NaN       NaN       NaN
    0.5000       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

I have to use this matrix for further calculation, so will these `NaN` affect my calculation?  If so, then how can I remove these keeping the matrix size same?

Comment: Yes, they may affect some of the calculations, but depending on what you are doing you want it that way. You can not "remove" them, but you could replace them.

Comment: What value should it be replaced by?

Comment: These NaN can be replaced by zeros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace the values in your matrix to some finite number, you can use [`isnan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) to help you do that.

Specifically, you can do something like this:

```
th1(isnan(th1)) = 0;
```

This will replace all `NaN` values with 0.  However, if you want to **remove** the `NaN` values, you can't do this with numeric matrices in MATLAB because MATLAB does not support uneven matrices.  Your only option would be a cell array and what you can do is make a cell array where each cell is a row from your matrix.

Specifically, you can do something like this:

```
th1_out = arrayfun(@(x) th1(x,~isnan(th1(x,:))), 1:size(th1,1), 'uni', 0);
```

Using your data, we get this:

```
>> celldisp(th1_out)

th1_out{1} =

    0.3333    0.6667    0.2500



th1_out{2} =

    0.5000         0    0.5000



th1_out{3} =

    0.5000



th1_out{4} =

    0.5000
```

---

However, you haven't really told me **what** calculations you intend to perform.  Depending on what calculations you want to perform, you don't even to replace any of the `NaN` values at all.  You can simply ignore them.  For example, let's say you wanted to find the average of every row in your matrix.  You'd simply count up the total amount of `NaN` values per row and take that into account when performing your mean.

In other words:

```
%// Create a temporary input matrix
th1_temp = th1;

%// Used to indicate what is NaN in your array
num_nan = isnan(th1);

%// Set the NaN values to zero in the temporary matrix
th1_temp(num_nan) = 0;

%// Calculate the average per row
average_th1 = sum(th1_temp, 2) ./ (size(th1,1) - sum(num_nan,2));
```

The logic of the above code is that we indicate what is `NaN` in your matrix, then if we wanted to find the average of each row, you would create a temporary data matrix that sets the `NaN` values to zero, then sum over each row and divide by the total number of elements *minus those elements that were classified as `NaN` per row*.  You subtract by this much because by setting the `NaN` values to 0, this will not accumulate anything when finding the average, but in order to remove the contribution of these 0 values in your average, you need to subtract by as many `NaN` values there were per row.

In the Statistics Toolbox, the above code can also be replicated using [`nanmean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html) but the above code is portable should you not have access to this toolbox.

If you wanted to calculate the average per column, a slight change to the last line of code is all that is required:

```
%// Calculate the average per column
average_th1 = sum(th1_temp, 1) ./ (size(th1,2) - sum(num_nan,1));
```

Essentially, I changed the 1s to 2s and the 2s to 1s.

Comment: @user5179049 - No problem at all.  Good luck!

Comment: i am working on semi markov model for predicting the probability of occuring of earthquake. For this i have to find the interval transition probability. For that i first have to calculate this matrix.It is holding time mass matrix. In this simply i have to replace these nan values by zeros. Because probability can not approach infinity, that these nan values in this matrix represent. So simply I assign these zero values, that simply means not possible in probabiltiy.

Comment: @user5179049 - I see!